# Neo4j Optional match not working on 2.2.1

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have users data like

```
    Id        Username 
 ---------------------------
    1         user1
    2         user2
    3         user3
    4         user4
    5         user5
```

There can be `friends` relation between users. 
Now suppose I am `user1` then I need a list of user with friends count and mutual frends count

In my database

- `user2` Have two friends `user3, user4`.
- `user4` is friend of `user3`

I have tried Like this

```
MATCH (me:user {is_deleted:false})
WHERE id(me)= 1
MATCH (allUser:user {is_deleted:false})
OPTIONAL MATCH (allUser)<-[all_friends:friends]-(f:user {is_deleted:false})
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[mutual_friends:friends]->(f)

RETURN id(allUser) AS user_id, allUser.username AS username, count(distinct(all_friends)), count(distinct(mutual_friends))
```

It Provide me count of `all_friend` correct.

but not getting `mutual_friends` count properly it return 0 even if there are realtions.

**NOTE**:-This query works fine on `neo4j 2.1` but not working on `neo4j 2.2`.

What should do in my query to make this working.

Please let me know if i should explain more about the quetion.

Thanks.

Comment: Please create a dataset for this using http://console.neo4j.org and share its URL here.

Comment: Is this really the node-id ? And are you sure you have an is_deleted flag? You don't show it in your data.

Comment: You don't use "me" in your query at all? Perhaps it is just a typo `me -> m` Also mutual friends refers to another user, not all users.

Comment: You can probably also model your is_deleted=false with an :Active label.